# HTML Error "End of File Reached When Inside an Attribute Value"

Tags: html

I noticed my code was truncated, so I looked at the source in Firefox. after mousing over the part in red, I got the error `end of file reached when inside an attribute value. Ignoring tag.` I see absolutely NO problems with my code, but just in case, here it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Magic Cards</title>
<h1>Magic Cards</h1>
<p>????
<br><a href="file:///C:\Libraries\Game Storylines\Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories\Card Index\Magic Cards\blizzard.html">Blizzard</a>
<br>???????
<br><a href="file:///C:\Libraries\Game Storylines\Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories\Card Index\Magic Cards\cure.html">Cure</a>
<br>???????
<br>????
<br>????
<br><a href="file:///C:\Libraries\Game Storylines\Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories\Card Index\Magic Cards\Simba.html>Simba</a>
<br>?????
<br>?????
<br>?????
<br>?????
<br>???????????
<br>?????
</html>
```

After this lne, `<br><a href="file:///C:\Libraries\Game Storylines\Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories\Card Index\Magic Cards\cure.html">Cure</a>` it cuts off at the next `<br>` tag

Comment: are there actually ?????? in your code?

Comment: Yeah, I'm typing up the journal for KH chain of memories, and I haven't completed it yet.

Comment: This error message is one of the most self-explanatory errors I've ever seen. It's literally that: it still thinks you're in an attr declaration at the end of the html file. So, you must be fooling it somehow, like by not closing your "s. I suggest using syntax highlighting to spot quotation mistakes in the future.

Comment: _absolutely NO problems with my code,_ - then clearly it works. Since it doesn't you should post the code that generates the problem. This version is heavily edited so there's no guarantee that anyone can find the fault.

Comment: @joeytje50, I just use notepad, as I don't know of any other programs for this.

Comment: @Mike W, This is the original code, no edits, completely original.

Comment: I personally use Notepad++ but there are also a lot of other programs that have this feature. There is a list of HTML rditors that have additional features [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors#Source_code_editors) (some of those may not have syntax highlighting though)

Comment: You can also, for testing, use an online [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (I do not recommend writing your whole code there though). Some of these are: http://jsfiddle.net, http://jsbin.com, http://codepen.io, or http://ace.ajax.org (which is used on wikipedia and cloud9)

Comment: Use <br /> instead of <br> in the same way you close an image tag ..close your tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a quote after .html

```
<a href="file:///C:\Libraries\Game Storylines\Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories\Card Index\Magic Cards\Simba.html>Simba</a>
```

the fix

```
<a href="file:///C:\Libraries\Game Storylines\Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories\Card Index\Magic Cards\Simba.html">Simba</a>
```

Edit : Also, like Matt Ball pointed out in the comments, you are missing `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

The bare minimum that you should ever have for html in your website is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
</head>
<body>
A lot of stuff usually goes here.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're using a html page exclusively for <(i)frame> usage, is the <title> still needed? I assume yes, but it's silly to add it...